# how to get rid of the cordova screen when you open the app

Tags: cordova

I created a small app and everything works great but I don't understand one thing, that is, when I start the app on the smartphone while the app is loading I get a white screen with the Cordova logo in the center.

How can I get rid of this screen?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Cordova splashscreen.

Edit the config.xml and point to a splash screen image

```
<platform name="ios">
<splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" />
<splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@2x~universal~comany.png" />
<splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@2x~universal~comcom.png" />
<splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@3x~universal~anyany.png" />
<splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@3x~universal~anycom.png" />
<splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@3x~universal~comany.png" />
```

You can read more here
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/11.x/core/features/splashscreen/